# clock_nanosleep not working?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I try to sleep for half a second with this snippet of code using clock_nanosleep, but i can't get it to work. My code always executes immediately, as if the sleep wasn't there. What am I doing wrong?

```
    while (true) 
{

    /* CRITICAL SECTION BEGIN */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    if (ret) {
        perror ("clock_gettime");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < some_value ; i++){
        /* Do some stuff */

    }
    /* Update sleep time */
    now.tv_nsec += 500000000;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    /* CRITICAL SECTION END */

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &debug);
    printf("Clockgoal - now: : %lu\n", now.tv_nsec - debug.tv_nsec);
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &now, NULL);

}
```

This is running as a pthread but it doesn't sleep at all. The printf output shows like this:

```
Done Updating Time!
Clockgoal - now: : 499997443
Done Updating Time!
Clockgoal - now: : 499997441
```

What am I doing wrong? (Do I need some specific kernel config to allow for this kind of sleep? I'm running on a pretty minimal gentoo, so maybe I have to check some configuration option?

In general, what I want to achieve is that this thread does some updates to some values, and then sleeps for half a second, INCLUDING the time it was working. If I'm doing it wrong, and there is a better alternative, please tell me, as I'm not bound to use clock_nanosleep for this, it just seemed to be the appropriate solution.

Comment: Curious: Why use `"%lu"` in `printf("Clockgoal - now: : %lu\n", now.tv_nsec - debug.tv_nsec);`?  Expect `"%ld"`  `struct timespec {
        time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
        long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};`

Comment: Uh, tbh because I was lazy and just wanted to see the value. It's a debug print that will be removed anyways, but you're right I should use the correct way to print.

Comment: I don't think you can just ignore the `tv_sec` field like that when you add 500000000 to `tv_nsec` - you probably need to handle overflow and increment `tv_sec` if necessary.

Comment: @PaulR but the second field is seconds, right? Do I have to set it to 0 explicitly? I thought it would be initialized correctly when getting the time with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now)`

Comment: The problem is when you add 500000000 - if the `tv_nsec` field exceeds 999999999 when you do this then you need to subtract 1000000000 and increment `tv_sec`.

Comment: @PaulR ah, I haven't thought about this, I'll give it a go and see if that works :)

Comment: Check the return value from your call to `clock_nanosleep()`. If `tv_nsec` is 1 billion or more, you will get a return value of `EINVAL` ("The value in the `tv_nsec` field was not in the range 0 to 999999999 or `tv_sec` was negative", as per the man page)

Comment: I've just added an answer showing how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle overflow when you add 0.5 s to `now`.

Change:

```
now.tv_nsec += 500000000;
```

to:

```
now.tv_nsec += 500000000L;            // add 0.5s
if (now.tv_nsec >= 1000000000L)       // if ns field overflows
{
    now.tv_nsec -= 1000000000L;       // handle "carry" to seconds field
    now.tv_sec++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the solution!